# Having trouble loading image

Tags: java, image, embedded-resource

I've been trying to load this image.png file that's located in my images folder:

In eclipse I've made a folder in my src folder called images and put the image there, so it should be part of my classpath.

However, when I try to use this image it does not work:

I've tried these:

```
Image image; 
String craft = "myApp/src/images/image.png";
ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon(craft); 
        image = ii.getImage();

Image image; 
String craft = "myApp/src/images/image.png"; 
ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource(craft));
        image = ii.getImage();
```

And various variations for String craft:

```
"images/image.png", "/images/image.png", "/myApp/src/images/image.png"
```

Comment: Do a `jar -tvf the.jar` on the Jar that is supposed to contain the image.  I bet it is either a) Not in the Jar or more likely b) not at the path you specified.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Who says it's a jar?

Comment: I might suggest that eclipse doesn't include your `src` path as part of it's classpath. Instead you should consider create a "resources" directory within your project and adding your resources to it.  To be generally safer, using `/` is a good idea when using `getClass().getResource(...)`, so long as the path to the resources is absolute...

Comment: @Boann  It was the same person that told *you* the OP needed ***you*** to ask obtuse questions on their behalf, as opposed to the (much more sensible) route of them ..just telling me that themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the image in:

```
src/images/foo.png
```

And use this code:

```
ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon("images/foo.png");
Image image = ii.getImage();
System.out.println(image != null);
```

The output will be:

```
true
```

... that is, the `Image` is not `null`...
... if your classpath is the default build path eclipse provides when creating your project (note: should be the same with Netbeans, etc.).

If you're using a different building script, be it Ant or Maven, you might need to change the path. You will certainly if it's a web application.

**Additional notes**

- [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4340653/file-path-to-resource-in-our-war-web-inf-folder) is a good SO thread on resource paths for web applications.
- [Here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) is the typical Maven folder layout - useful to get you
  started if you use Maven as your build/package script.

Comment: Thanks this was so helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you are trying to load a resource in classpath, you need to specify the correct relative path. if you have your images folder in classpath as that of the classes, then you have to load it as follows

```
String craft = "images/image.png"; 
ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource(craft));
```

or if you have all the files in images folder in classpath, you can just specify the file name directly as well

```
   String craft = "image.png"; 
    ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon(craft);
```

So, i am sure the path you have given is wrong and that's why the resource is not getting loaded

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
String craft = "images/image.png"; 
ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon(craft);
```

File structure

```
ProjectRoot
          images
               imgage.png
          src
          bin
```