# Access files inside WEB-INF | Java

Tags: java, file-io

I am trying to access a `.properties` file inside the web-inf folder in java, but I could not figure out how to do it.

If the file cannot be accessed, why is that?

Yet, I can access files from inside the package. The code for that is as follows:

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
        InputStream in = ReadPropertyFile.class.getResourceAsStream("temp.properties");
        prop.load(in);
        System.out.println(prop.getProperty("asd"));
        in.close();
```

So how to achieve this inside a java class?

Comment: use the full path of properties file.

Comment: ya i tried WEB-INF/temp.properties..it is throwing null pointer

Comment: try this path rather `/yourappname/web-inf/`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4340653/file-path-to-resource-in-our-war-web-inf-folder

Comment: Try `/WEB-INF/temp.properties`

Comment: ya,alex i tried..gettting null

Comment: It's WEB-INF/classes that's in the classpath, not WEB-INF/ . So a viable solution is to put your properties file underneath WEB-INF/classes - not pretty, but should do! Edit: I suppose the solution in the link given by @PeterMmm is better...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried using below code.

```
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        prop.load(new FileInputStream("./WebContent/WEB-INF/my.properties"));
        System.out.println(prop.getProperty("data"));
```

and it worked.