# Read APN Certificate file in classpath of war web project

Tags: java, ios, jakarta-ee

I am developing a web project and after mvn build proper war file is created.
In thisproject I am creating an APN service by giveing the full certification path which is pointing in local directory like "file:c:certification.p12"

```
ApnsService service = APNS.newService().withReconnectPolicy(new ApnReconnectPolicy()).withConnectTimeout(apnSockectTimeout).withCert(certificatePath, certificatePassword).
```

I would like to know if I can put certification.p12 file in war file and access it in classpath decription

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,

It's recommended to use context.getRealPath or context.getRessource method to not care about where the application is deployed. Don't forget to hide your file in the WEB-INF , if not it can be downloaded as a simple file.

See : [File path to resource in our war/WEB-INF folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4340653/file-path-to-resource-in-our-war-web-inf-folder)

Yours