# Cannot access CSS files defined under WEB-INF from JSP

Tags: java, html, css, jsp, struts2

I have created Struts2 application using Maven. In this application I have created two namespaces, first is `tc` and the second one is `cmpui`. From the JSP page, I am trying to access `.css` files, but it is giving me 404 error.

Location of JSP page is :

```
webapp\tc\layout\stylesheets.jsp
```

Location of CSS file is :

```
WEB-INF\css\default.css
```

Code on JSP page is

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../WEB-INF/css/default.css">
```

Any suggestion please.

Comment: What is the full path of stylesheets.jsp and default.css? I think your href is wrong.

Comment: You can not access resource directly which are in WEB-INF but you could using context object, This link might help ful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4340653/file-path-to-resource-in-our-war-web-inf-folder

Comment: Thanks for the reply guys. I have made some changes in jsp page but still it is giving me same error. Currently in browser, path for css is showing as http://servername:port/contextpath/css/default.css

Comment: Please Find the folder Structure for the reference.


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/vx3Mf.png

Comment: Put css outside of web-inf directory. And use `<s:url>` tag to reference them.

Comment: @AleksandrM : If I put css folder outside WEB-INF Folder, it will be consider as another namespace, right? Correct me if I am wrong. And also I want to create folder for js files. Do I need to create outside WEB-INF folder?

Comment: What do you mean by another namespace? IMO you can ignore namespaces right now and solve your current problem. Yes, outside of web-inf for js files also.

Comment: Thanks for reply Aleksandr M. Css files are accessible if I put css folder outside WEB-INF folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not access a resources that are under `WEB-INF` folder. Move your static resources to another place accessible by Struts2 (for example, web root). And use [`s:url`](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/url.html) tag to build the URL.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<s:url value='/css/default.css'/>">
```