# My CSS doesn't show if i put my CSS folder inside the WEB-INF folder

Tags: java, html, css, spring, spring-mvc

I'm working in a Spring MVC project and I have the following problem:

This is my folders hierarchy

```
--src
   --main
      --webapp
         --WEB-INF
            --views
                --css
                   --mystyle.css
                ---myview.html
```

and this is how I call `mystyle.css` in `myview.html`

```
href="css/mystyle.css"
```

but my CSS doesn't show up.

But if I put my `views` folder outside of `WEB_INF`, my CSS does show up and it works like this:

```
--src
   --main
      --webapp
          --views
              --css
                 --mystyle.css
              --myview.html
         --WEB-INF
```

And I call my CSS the same way like before `href="css/mystyle.css"`

Is there something different that I didn't notice? Why doesn't my CSS works outside of the `WEB-INF` folder and it does not work inside?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot access CSS files defined under WEB-INF from JSP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26463168/cannot-access-css-files-defined-under-web-inf-from-jsp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it is true that you cannot access resources under `WEB-INF` folder directly, you can still keep your location and add a configuration like

```
 <resources mapping="/css/**" location="/WEB-INF/views/css/" />
```

in your spring mvc configuration, or a java config equivalent if you're using java config. Note that you should be accessing css with an absolute URL, so if you're serving from root

```
href="/css/mystyle.css"
```

or prepand a context if you're using one

Answer (score 1):

Right, CSS files need to be in a path that is directly visible to the browser. WEB-INF is hidden.