# Insert image in jsp

Tags: html, image, jsp, struts2

I'am using Struts2 project with tomcat server and I want to load pictures from my project I put the picture into webapp/WEB-INF/images/image.png and this in jsp `<img src="WEB-INF/images/image.png">` but I've go this as en error in the browser

> GET http://localhost:8080/crudreverse/WEB-INF/images/image.png 404

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26482243/573032

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Files under `WEB-INF` are, by design, not directly accessible to clients, unless you disable normal security precautions (please don't).

Images (in general) should not be stored in the app itself, but if they are, they need to not be under `WEB-INF`.

If they *are* under `WEB-INF` "on purpose" then you need an endpoint to stream those images, but there's little reason to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `<img src="images/image.png">`