# Scalatra : Access file path from a deployed application

Tags: scalatra, scalatra-sbt

I need to access file path on the server in Scalatra application. Without war file the following worked for me where file was stored in /src/main/resources/data location.

> this.getClass.getResource("/data").getPath

However the same doesn't work with deployed app. Any ideas how should I get the context.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

This question is almost same as [How to get the path of a running JAR file?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/320595/2565527)
But, in Scala case, you can use:

```
new File(classOf[YourClassName].getProtectionDomain.getCodeSource.getLocation.toURI.getPath)
```

For example, to find web.xml is:
[File path to resource in our war/WEB-INF folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4342095/2565527)

```
val context: ServletContext = getServletContext()
val fullPath = context.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/web.xml")
```