# FileOutputStream paths in java/jsp web application

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications, fileoutputstream, file-writing

I have a simple java web application with following folder structure.

[image]

When I deploy the web app it has data.json file in WEB-INF/classes folder. I need to write data to this file from controller.java class controller package which is in WEB-INF/classes folder.

I tried following code.

```
FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("..\\data.json", true);
output.write(jsonObject.toJSONString().getBytes());
output.flush();
```

This doesn't give me any error which suggest that the operation happen in a file somewhere in my computer.

How can I write to the data.json file? I can't give absolute path here.

Comment: Take a look at this post may helps you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4340653/file-path-to-resource-in-our-war-web-inf-folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code worked,

```
FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream( request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("WEB-INF/classes/data.json"), false);
```

Answer (score 2):

WEB-INF/classes is for the class-path. Files there should be considered read-only, cacheable **resources** (`getResource, getResourceAsStream`).

The `HttpRequest.getServletContext().getRealPath("/WEB-INF")` can be used,
for file system paths.

I suggest using the classes files as *template*, copied the first time to a real file system path, and then being overwritten.

Use `/`, not Windows `\\`.

Use `close()` and then `flush()` is not needed.

Use `getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)`.

Comment: Is it okay to put data.json file in WEB-INF folder outside classes folder?

Comment: outside WEB-INF it will be directly accessible to outside world. any request to /yourapp/data.json will serve that file unless you explicitly protect it.

Comment: What is the HTTPRequest here? How can I obtain that. I could pass a `HttpServletRequest` object from jsp to java file, but it does not contain a getServeletContext() method.

Comment: Yes that is what I meant