# Unable to access folder location war!\WEB-INF\classes\ in packaged war with Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, imagemagick, war, im4java

I want to access my resource folder path which is inside the packaged WAR created by spring boot. I have looked this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4340653/file-path-to-resource-in-our-war-web-inf-folder?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa), which is to access specific file at some location but I am looking for just the folder location.

With WAR file getRealPath() / getAbsolutePath() does not work, below is the snippet

```
String contextPath = event.getServletContext().getRealPath("/WEB-INF/scripts/views/");
```

One more scenario wherein I want to access ImageMagic tool which is packaged inside war at "WEB-INF/classes/ImageMagick-6.6.1-5" location but it is not accessed by the im4java library. Providing any drive location like "C:/ImageMagick-6.6.1-5" will work.

```
String bindir = URLDecoder.decode(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("ImageMagick-6.6.1-5").getPath());
```

Is there any workaround to access the location of directory inside WAR.

Comment: Facing the same issue!!!